# How to stop Canon 5D Mk IV from switching to SD card automatically when CF card is removed?

Tags: canon, sdcard, canon-5d-mark-iv

I have both a CF and an SD card in a 5D Mk IV when shooting.
"Record func+card/folder sel." is set to "Standard" and the camera is set to use the CF card.

However, whenever I turn off the camera and remove the CF card to import photos to my computer, the camera automatically switches to the SD card the next time I turn it on, even if I do not turn the camera on until the CF card is back in the camera.

Does anyone encounter the same issue and may anyone please tell me how I can avoid having to specify which card to record on every time?

Comment: Have you tried taking the SD card out with the CF card?

Comment: Did you format the card in reader? If yes, don't, do it in camera. And try w/o switch off the camera (it work for me on Mark III)

Comment: @xiota I have not tried that yet, but will try that next time. It's still a little nuisance, but it is not as annoying as having to change settings every time.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I do not format the card in the reader. By "try w/o switch off the camera" do you mean leave the camera on and then remove the CF card?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, right, just keep camera on and try.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thank you. I will get back to you after I try that.

Comment: No, do not remove the card while the camera is on, you're only asking for problems.

Comment: @MikeDixon, as far as I remember Canon recommendation is to not remove the card when the light (for card write operations) is on

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Can you confirm whether [Mike Sowsun's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/107847/75526) works (keep memory card door open)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave the memory card door open after you remove the CF card, it will stay in CF card priority.

There is also a firmware add-on for certain Canon cameras called "[Magic Lantern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Lantern_(firmware))". Magic Lantern is not yet available for the 5D Mark IV but on the 5D Mark III, it adds many useful tools and features to the basic Canon menu options. One of these is the option to always select the CF card.

[image]

Comment: Magic Lantern may never be available for the 5D Mark IV. They haven't even gotten the 7D Mark II from 2014 stable yet.

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> How to stop Canon 5D Mk IV from switching to SD card automatically when CF card is removed?

Remove the SD card first. If there's no card in the SD slot when you close the card access door, the camera will not automatically switch.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution as well, and it works. However, I consider it a slight nuisance having to remove both cards even if I only want to remove one, so I will go with leaving the card door open.